# Cannot access json values after converting from xml using xml-js parser

Tags: node.js, json, xml

I parse the xml using the following code

```
var convert = require('xml-js');
var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('./2B2DE7DD-FD11-4F2C-AF0D-A244E5977CBA.xml', 'utf8');
result = convert.xml2json(xml, { spaces: 4});
```

The result throws the following JSON

```
{
    "declaration": {
        "attributes": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "encoding": "utf-8"
        }
    }
}
```

However if i try accesing "declaration" using `result["declaration"]`the console returns `undefined`

Should i use another parser or is there something wrong with getting the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `xml2js` instead of `xml2json` if you want it return object.

```
result = convert.xml2js(xml, options);    // to convert xml text to javascript object
result = convert.xml2json(xml, options);  // to convert xml text to json text
```

Answer (score 1):

The data type of `result` is String, not JavaScript object. That is, the `convert.xml2json(xml, { spaces: 4});` statement will return a JSON String, not JS object.

To access `declaration`, you need to parse the JSON string to object:

```
var convert = require('xml-js');
var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('./2B2DE7DD-FD11-4F2C-AF0D-A244E5977CBA.xml', 'utf8');
result = convert.xml2json(xml, { spaces: 4});

result = JSON.parse(result);
```